# Calling a "non-void" method from another Java class

Tags: java, class, methods

This is the method I am attempting to call:

```
public static int seu03Menu(int option)
{
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("*************************************************************");
System.out.println("Welcome to the 1323 System \nPlease choose an option from our menu\n");
System.out.println("1. Calculator");
System.out.println("2. Sentence Analysis");
System.out.println("3. Roll Dice");
System.out.println("4. Big Money");
System.out.println("\n9. Exit");
System.out.println("Option:");
option = console.nextInt();
return option;
}
```

This is how I am trying to call the method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
seu03Methods.seu03Menu(int option);
switch (option)
{
case 1:
    seu02.calculator();
    break;
case 2:
    seu03Methods.sentenceAnalysis();
    break;
case 3:
    seu03Methods.rollDice();
    break;
case 4:
    seu03Methods.bigMoney();
    break;
case 9:
    System.out.println("Exiting seu03...");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
    break;
}
```

We haven't covered how to call methods that aren't just "public static void" so I am completely lost. I'm new to Java so trying to search for this using Google and Stack Overflow was to no avail. Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are both the functions in the same class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int option = seu03Methods.seu03Menu (0);
```

`seu03Menu` should not take a parameter.  In Java, parameters are values that get passed *into* a method; the only values that get passed *out* of the method, back to the caller, are the return value.  The `seu03Menu` does not use the value of `option` that gets passed into it.  Therefore, it shouldn't take a parameter, and instead it should look like

```
public static int seu03Menu()
{
... other stuff
int option = console.nextInt();
return option;
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
int option = seu03Methods.seu03Menu ();
```

If `seu03Menu` isn't something you can change, then you have to pass it some integer as a parameter.  But since `seu03Menu` doesn't use the value you pass it, you can make it anything you want, like `0`.

Comment: Alright, good stuff. Now I just have to finish teaching myself about switches to get this working right and we'll be all good. My prof is so enthusiastic but rarely covers all the material we need to :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method you're calling returns `int`.

You need to initialize a reference to the method's value in your code, in order to get the method's value.

You also don't need to add a parameter to the method's signature, since it generates its result from the outcome of what's been scanned in the `System` input stream (`System.in`).

You can do that as such:

- change the method signature to no parameters: `public static int seu03Menu()`
- in your method's body, change `option = console.nextInt();` with `return console.nextInt();`
- call your method as such: `int theResult = seu03Methods.seu03Menu();`

Your method will take an `int` typed value from the `System.in` stream, then return it. 
Your `theResult` method-scoped variable will hold that value.

Additionally, I strongly recommend:

- checking for exceptions in the method's body (what happens if you type a non-integer value once queried? try for yourself)
- using Java-conventions (class names CamelCase)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int seu03Menu(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    //All your options

    int option = console.nextInt();
    return option;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
  int option = seu03Methods.seu03Menu();
   switch( option ){
     //rest of your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes like this:
change line in main
seu03Methods.seu03Menu(int option);

to

int option=seu03Methods.seu03Menu;

and
change definition of method 
public static int seu03Menu(int option) to public static int seu03Menu()